# Company Page editor raises a Syntax Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` in this part of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Careers.using(["shared", "tagEditor", "companyPagesEdit"], function() {
        var config = {…});
        Careers.companyPagesEdit.init(config);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What company page?

Comment: @Jon there's such a thing on Careers.

Comment: @nicael It was more of a hint to link to that page really. If you're reporting a bug somewhere then it's useful to actually link to the place that's causing the issue.

Comment: Editor is private so I can't really provide a useful link to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know!

Many of our developers own cats. In this case, the only logical explanation for what happened is that one of these cats stood on a developer's keyboard and inserted an additional closing bracket in a JavaScript file, causing a syntax error on the page.

The extra bracket has now been removed, so the company page editor is now working properly.

To prevent this happening again, <s>the cat has been put down</s> we are looking at more effective monitoring of client-side JavaScript errors so we spot it when things break before you do!

Comment: So, [tag:status-completed]? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Any time! Thanks for the quick response. :-)

Comment: I'm a cat and I'd like to say that it's my human who stepped on the keyboard, not the opposite